# Creating table with data from raster to samples

Tags: qgis, raster

How do I obtain a table with the data of a raster for my single points in the map?

The image might be helpful.  What I want to do is to have a table with the value from the 'Elevation' raster to my '1001 genomes' samples.

[image]

Comment: `add raster values to points` does what you're asking for.

Comment: You could also have a look at the QGIS point sampling plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/

Answer (score 3):

No need for a plugin. Just run "Sample Raster Values" from processing toolbox. It will extract raster values on your desired points and create a new point layer having your rastervalues at these locations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that I get this error: 'ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point.'. Do you kow where the problem might be?

Comment: @SimoneCastellana One of your points obviously has no geometry. Try running "Check Validity" from processing toolbox on your point layer first. Then try the "valid" output of it on "sample raster values" again.

Comment: Thank you very much I have solved the probelm!!